# How to set null foreign key in Entity Framework code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Order < Customer model.

How do I set this up? When I try to insert a user with a null customerid, it tells me that it cannot be null.

The model is as follows:

```
public class Order
{
    public long OrderID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }   
}
```

In `DbContext` :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Orders)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Customer)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: You need to make the `CustomerID` property nullable: `public int? CustomerID { get; set; }`

Comment: Could you clarify your questions, as I don't understand "*A user belongs to a country, but may not belong to any (null foreign key)*". What does that mean to you? What does it have to do with the *Order* class you present? Please be a bit more precise with your question. Optionally, from what I can observe you can try to make the `CustomerID` property nullable. (*edit:* just like @Felipe Cruze just mentioned above :))

Comment: You are talking about problems with user and country but the code deals with customer and order. Did not make sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to replace line

```
.WithRequired(e => e.Customer)
```

with

```
.WithOptional(e => e.Customer)
```

?

And I make the CustomerID property nullable: public int? CustomerID { get; set; }